# Make migrations using models corresponding to the different databases in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my models.py file in app.

from django.db import models

```
class ImaraInventory(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qty = models.BigIntegerField()
    sku_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_virtual = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('channel_type', 'branch', 'partner_id', 'day', 'sku_id')



class ImaraSales(models.Model):
    attribution = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku_id  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    live = models.BooleanField()
    disc_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=12)
    revenue = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=12)
    sales_qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('attribution', 'branch' , 'channel_type', 'day', 'partner_id', 'sku_id')


class ImaraReturns(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    return_qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together =  ('branch', 'channel_type', 'partner_id', 'sku_id', 'day')



class WrognInventory(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qty = models.BigIntegerField()
    sku_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_virtual = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('channel_type', 'branch', 'partner_id', 'day', 'sku_id')



class WrognSales(models.Model):
    attribution = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku_id  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    live = models.BooleanField()
    disc_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=12)
    revenue = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=12)
    sales_qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('attribution', 'branch' , 'channel_type', 'day', 'partner_id', 'sku_id')



class WrognReturns(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    return_qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together =  ('branch', 'channel_type', 'partner_id', 'sku_id', 'day')



class MstakenInventory(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qty = models.BigIntegerField()
    sku_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_virtual = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('channel_type', 'branch', 'partner_id', 'day', 'sku_id')


class MstakenSales(models.Model):
    attribution = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku_id  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    live = models.BooleanField()
    disc_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=12)
    revenue = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=12)
    sales_qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('attribution', 'branch' , 'channel_type', 'day', 'partner_id', 'sku_id')



class MstakenReturns(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partner_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day = models.DateField()
    return_qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together =  ('branch', 'channel_type', 'partner_id', 'sku_id', 'day')
```

This is my dbrouters.py file in app.

```
from etl.models import WrognSales,WrognInventory, WrognReturns
from etl.models import ImaraSales, ImaraInventory, ImaraReturns
from etl.models import MstakenSales, MstakenInventory, MstakenReturns

class WrognDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model,**hints):
        if model == WrognSales or model == WrognInventory or model == WrognReturns:
            return 'db_usplwrogn'

    def db_for_write(self,model,**hints):
        if model == WrognSales or model == WrognInventory or model == WrognReturns:
            return 'db_usplwrogn'



class ImaraDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model,**hints):
        if model == ImaraInventory or model == ImaraReturns or model == ImaraSales:
            return 'db_usplimara'

    def db_for_write(self,model,**hints):
        if model == ImaraInventory or model == ImaraReturns or model == ImaraSales:
            return 'db_usplimara'


class MstakenDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model,**hints):
        if model == MstakenInventory or model == MstakenReturns or model == MstakenSales:
            return 'db_usplmstaken'

    def db_for_write(self,model,**hints):
        if model == MstakenInventory or model == MstakenReturns or model == MstakenSales:
            return 'db_usplmstaken'
```

These all are the databases in settings.py file.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'etlui',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
      'USER': '***',
      'PASSWORD': '***',
  },
  'db_usplimara':{
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'usplimara',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
      'USER': '***',
      'PASSWORD': '***',
  },
  'db_usplmstaken':{
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'usplmstaken',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
      'USER': '***',
      'PASSWORD': '***',
  },
  'db_usplwrogn':{
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'usplwrogn',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
      'USER': '**',
      'PASSWORD': '***',
  }

}
```

I want to make the migrations to different databases according to the model for each client. I executed the command "python manage.py makemigrations app_name" and then migrate using this command "python manage.py migrate --database=db_usplmstaken" for each database. But it created all the nine models in all the three databases.
Please let me know how to migrate according to the models corresponding to each database.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating multiple databases in **Django** is easy, but redundant: The migrate command only operates on one database at a time, so you must run it separately for each database.

To migrate the second database, you simply run `python manage.py migrate --database=example_db`.

This is fine in production, when you aren’t often migrating, but during active development on your local environment, it can get tiring. To solve this, we use [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/) to simplify complex tasks. In this specific instance, we have one command that runs the migrations on both of our development databases.

You can also visit following link for more description:
https://kite.com/python/docs/fabric

Answer (score 0):

The important is not db_for_read and db_for_write, when you use a migrate command, the important is the allow_migrate function.

For example:

```
class WrognDBRouter(object):

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if model_name in ['WrognSales', 'WrognInventory', 'WrognReturns'] and db == 'db_usplwrogn':
            return True
```

You select a model_name and database and allow the migrations.

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate